# ¿Hay un "Imports System.Console" (VB.NET) en C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, consola

Quisiera saber si hay algo así como un `using System.Console` en **C#**.

Quería ponerme a hacer algo en consola para recordar. Cuando aprendí a usar la consola, lo hice con el lenguaje **VB.NET**. Allí podía importar el espacio de nombres llamado `System.Console` para no repetir la palabra `Console` por todo el código.

... y quiero hacer lo mismo, pero no encuentro un `using` así en **C#**.

**Ejemplo de espacio de nombres en Visual Basic**

```vb
'SIN EL ESPACIO DE NOMBRES ("Console." en cada línea del código)
Module Module1
    Sub Main() 
        Console.WriteLine("HOLA")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

'CON EL ESPACIO DE NOMBRES (desaparece el "Console.", lo que quiero en C#)
Imports System.Console
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        WriteLine("HOLA")
        ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module>
```

En fin, lo que quisiera saber es si me toca escribir el `Console.` siempre en **C#**, o si hay forma de no hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pides sí es posible, pero solo a partir de C# 6 en adelante (Visual Studio 2015+). Se logra con el `using static`. Puedes encontrar la documentación sobre su uso aquí: [using (Directiva, Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Ejemplo:

```
using static System.Console;

// ....

static void Main()
{
    WriteLine("hola mundo");
}
```

Comment: Perfecto a esto me refereria gracias

Answer (score 2):

C#, Si usas el namespace [System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
...
...
...
    Console.WriteLine()
```

si no, simplemente has referencia a la clase [Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx) y su namespace

```
System.Console.WriteLine()
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, puedes escribir únicamente:

```
using static System.Console;
...
...
    WriteLine("HOLA")
    ReadLine()
```

**Si estas usando C# de Visual Studio 2015 o posterior.**

Comment: Sí es posible de escribir solamente `WriteLine("HOLA")`, a partir de C# 6 en adelante.